# $provider = function() vs function provider()

Tags: php, function

I've seen in various coding examples different coding style when creating functions.

What is the difference between creating a function using

```php
$provider = function() { code here }
```

vs

```php
function provider(){ code here }
```

Is the first example simply a short version of: `$data = provider();` ?
When do we use the first example?

Comment: `$provider = function() {...}` creates a variable called $provider that can be passed as an argument to other functions; but is also an executable function in its own right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. First code is declaration of [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php), i.e. anonymous function. It has no name and can be called with identifier that holds it. Second sample is [normal function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) (user-defined function, to be more specific) and, thus, it will be accessible within all scopes via it's name - not like closure, which will be available for calling only within scope, where it was defined.

You can have as many closures as you wish - they are just callable entities, for example this is valid:

```
$provider = function() { Code here }
$another  = function() { Code here } //same code
```

-and calling `$provider` (for example, with [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/call_user_func)) will have nothing to do with `$another`

Another significant difference is that closure can accept *context parameters* like:

```
$provider = function() use ($param1, $param2, ...) { Code here }
```

-so inside it's body *context parameters* will be available. Context parameters are not like usual arguments - since context parameters defined and exist independent from closure while arguments are evaluated at the moment, when call happened.

Answer (score 0):

First declaration is anonymous function.And after assignment,we have variable with name $provider and can call $provider() .Second declaration its just normally function.
Anonymous function can be user for example in array_map,array_filter.For example

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$res = array_filter(
    $a, function ($elem) {
        return $elem > 3;
    }
);
print_r($res);
```

output element who larger 3